# Trouble iterating/mapping props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to develop a simple application in which any number of tasks will be rendered as cards. I'm passing them as props, schemed like so:

```
taskList: [{
            taskID: 1,
            taskTitle: 'Task 1',
            taskDescription: 'Description 1',
            completed: true
        }]
```

[image: Scheme of the application]

By logging the props in the TaskCard component, I can see the list arrives exactly like that. If I try and log something such as `props[0].taskDescription`, it'll successfully return "Description 1", like so:

```
export default function TaskCard(props) {
return(
    <div className="task-card" draggable>
        <h3> Test </h3>
        { props[0].taskDescription } // this actually works
    </div>
)
}
```

I can't, however, map or calculate the length of the props to iterate through props.

What am I doing wrong in terms of iteration? Is it a flawed architecture in terms of componentization?

Comment: show where you are passing the props?

Comment: If `props[0].taskDescription` works that suggests you're passing an array *as* the props, which is unusual - typically it would be *one of* the props, e.g. `{ tasks: [...] }`.

Comment: props should be an object

Comment: I concur with @jonrsharpe and @chandradeepta , it would then be something like `props.tasks[0].taskDescription`. In other words, in this case your `props` is an `array` not an `object` as it typically should. Makes sense?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, folks. I'll rework on the props passing as object and post the solution here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To render a list of TaskCards, you need to do the mapping of `taskList` outside that component like so:

```js
{taskList.map(task => <TaskCard task={task} />)}
```

and then `TaskCard` would render using the passed `task` props:

```js
TaskCard(props) {
// use props.task.taskDescription, etc.
}
```

Comment: This doesn't address OP's issue, its merely a best practice recommendation

Comment: Thank you, frozen. But it is as @AnuragSrivastava mentioned. As shown in the image, there are two levels of props passing. The question was more directed as how to iterate in the final component. If I apply this solution one level above the task card, I'll face the same challenge as I was passing an array as props to it. The comments to the main question shed some light on the matter. I'll work further and share the answer here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, thank you all who contributed with your insights in the comments for the original posting. So yes, apparently passing an array as a prop is troublesome. I may not have resolved in the most efficient way, but here's what it has come down to so far. Use the image in the original post to guide yourself.

I have resolved the issue the following way:

**UserArea.jsx**

- Contains a state that logs the user, username, a list containing pending tasks `pendingList` and a list containing complete tasks `completedList`;
- It renders a header, the PendingArea and CompleteArea component passing `{...this.state}` to each of them (the full component is an object).

  ```
  render(){
      return(
          <div className="user-area-container">
              <div className="profile-header">
                  <h2>{ this.state.userName }</h2>
                      { this.state.email }
              </div>

              <PendingArea {...this.state} />
              <CompletedArea {...this.state} />
          </div>
      )
  }
  ```

**PendingArea.jsx and CompleteArea.jsx**

Here I made the filtering, passing only the equivalent mapping to each of the components. The code for the PendingArea component is as follows:

```
function PendingArea(props) {

var pendingTasks = props.pendingList.map(task => {
    return <TaskCard {...task} />
});

return(
    <div className="status-container">
        <div className="status-title">
            <h2>Pending tasks</h2>
        </div>

        <div className="status-modifier">
            { pendingTasks }
        </div>
    </div>
)
}
```

**TaskCards.jsx**

Finally, the TaskCard component uses the direct properties from the props:

```
export default function TaskCard(props) {
return(
    <div className="task-card" draggable>
        <h3> { props.taskTitle } </h3>
        { props.taskDescription }
    </div>
)
}
```

This way I managed to properly render the task card in their due place. I hope this works for anyone reading this, as well.